# How to generate data for matplotlib filled contour plots given the real coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

What I have is a normal set of coordinates like, point A [1, 2, 3]; point B [3, 6, 5] etc...

What I wanted to have is somewhat like this:
[image]
The code (by matplotlib) is the following:

```
"""
.. versionadded:: 1.1.0
   This demo depends on new features added to contourf3d.
"""

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(1.0)
print X
print(Y)
print(Z)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

I wanted to understand how do these X, Y and Z work.
So printed statements have shown me:

```
[[-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]
 [-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]
 [-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]
 [-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]
 [-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]
 [-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]]
[[-30. -30. -30. -30. -30. -30.]
 [-20. -20. -20. -20. -20. -20.]
 [-10. -10. -10. -10. -10. -10.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 10.  10.  10.  10.  10.  10.]
 [ 20.  20.  20.  20.  20.  20.]]
[[ -9.82064017e-03  -1.19639890e-01  -5.36188786e-01  -8.84025856e-01
   -5.36188786e-01  -1.19639890e-01]
 [ -1.19639843e-01  -1.45751201e+00  -6.53211598e+00  -1.07696384e+01
   -6.53211503e+00  -1.45751094e+00]
 [ -5.35172034e-01  -6.52729956e+00  -2.92602828e+01  -4.82376751e+01
   -2.92393221e+01  -6.50361544e+00]
 [ -4.73838989e-01  -8.82629001e+00  -4.23628013e+01  -6.80792672e+01
   -3.39066568e+01   7.28564728e-01]
 [  2.49470498e+00   7.82740289e+00   1.43454530e+01   3.66947009e+01
    7.68283796e+01   7.84287606e+01]
 [  2.90546977e-01   4.85837411e-01  -6.28741676e-01   7.28564728e-01
    7.82740289e+00   1.00406921e+01]]
```

As far as I understand first row `[[-30. -20. -10.   0.  10.  20.]` for any point at X, given constant Y of -30 (`[[-30. -30. -30. -30. -30. -30.]`) the height (Z) is `[[ -9.82064017e-03  -1.19639890e-01  -5.36188786e-01  -8.84025856e-01 -5.36188786e-01  -1.19639890e-01]` That's good, but in the real life data, it's more probable, that you have somewhat like:

```
X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [4, 5, 6]
Z = [10, 9, 10]
```

So it's not really like everything is defined, rather than you have some points, i.e. a = [1, 4, 10], b = [2, 5, 9] and c = [3, 6, 10]. It's not really like you have a1 = [1, 4, 10], a2 = [2, 4, 10], a3 = [3, 4, 10] and so on. So, given the data as it usually appears, how would one build a 3D contour plot?

I also know that I need a 2D numpy array, here's explained how to get one: [Make 2D Numpy array from coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796038/make-2d-numpy-array-from-coordinates)
What I still don't understand is how to convert/use some real coordinates data.

If I am plotting the points as a scatter plot, here's what I get:

[image]

I would like to create a surface over the scatters, as they definitely form some relief with peaks and plains.

Comment: What does your actual data look like?  Is it missing a few points of the grid or do you really only have three points?  1) If it's just missing a few points, you can make a grid and mask out those points; 2) You can interpolate to fill in missing points; 3) You could make a scatter plot rather than a contour plot.  It's hard to know what to suggest since you spend all your efforts describing what your data isn't rather than what it is.

Comment: @tom10, no there's just a set of points. I can plot a scatter plot. What I would like to do is to create a surface for these points. They are in form of arrays, like such arrX = [1, 2, 3]; arrY = [3, 4, 5]; arrZ = [10, 9, 8]. I also tried like that: arrX = [[1], [2], [3]] (same for Y and Z), but it didn't work out.

Comment: Your edits are much more helpful to see what you want, but it doesn't seem like you want a contour plot.  Maybe you just want to 2D histogram?  I see the link to the 2D histrogram, and I don't really understand why that doesn't work for you.  You might also want something else though, like a 2D fit that you can tune to your specific needs, etc.  (Also, I don't want to chase this around, so I'm not going to continue to follow this conversation.)

Comment: @tom10 I need a 3d relief.

Comment: Yes, but a 2D histogram gives you a 3D relief.  2D refers to (X,Y), then the histogram gives Z.

Comment: If you just simulated a bit of data in the form you need, and made clear what you wanted as the figure, this would take 2 minutes to answer.

Comment: If you were to fit a surface to those points, would you want it to track *all* of the peaks and valleys in the z-axis, or should some of that variability be treated as noise and smoothed over?

Comment: @tom10 'What I wanted to have is somewhat like this:' it's the second sentence in my question and there's an image. Unfortunately, my data, when I try to simulate it like this gives nothing. So I just see the axes and nothing.

Comment: @ali_m I think that if I smooth, it's OK. I am mostly interested in the highest/lowest peaks.

Comment: @ali_m The image which I have in my head looks like if I had those points as real objects in space and would throw a piece of cloth onto them, so the cloth would create a surface following the major peaks and deepenings. That's the effect I am trying to achieve

Comment: How about this: grid your X,Y space and find the max Z value within each grid square (and 0 or some other value if there's nothing in the square), and then use these max values for your contour plot?  I suggest this because draping a piece of cloth sounds like you're interested in local maximum values.

Comment: @tom10 I understood!!! Sounds very cool!!! I will try to code this asap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your heart is set on a 3D surface plot, you have two main options:

1. Plot your irregularly sampled data directly
2. Resample your data on a regular grid

If you go for option 1 you could use [`plot_trisurf`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html?highlight=trisurf#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf), which uses [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) in order to infer which points should be connected by lines in order to create the surface. My guess is that this will probably look messy, since it doesn't by itself apply any sort of smoothing or interpolation. If you have lots of then it will probably take a long time to render as well.

If you go for option 2 then you have a wide variety of choices in terms of how you resample the data. One of the simplest options would be to compute a weighted 2D histogram, e.g. using [`np.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[nx, ny], weights=z)
```

`H` will be an `(nx, ny)` 2D array where `X[i, j]` gives the mean z-value for all the points that fall within the bin specified by `xedges[i:i+1]` and `yedges[i:i+1]` (see the documentation for full details). To plot this as a 3D surface you could then use [`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html?highlight=trisurf#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'})
xcentres = (xedges[1:] + xedges[:-1]) / 2
ycentres = (yedges[1:] + yedges[:-1]) / 2
xc, yc = np.ix_(xcentres, ycentres)
ax.plot_surface(xc, yc, H, cmap='Blues', alpha=0.5)
```

In terms of choosing the histogram bin size there will be a trade-off between making the histogram look smooth and capturing the structure within your dataset.

Aside from computing a histogram, you could also use *interpolation* or *smoothing*. These both involve fitting some function to your data that can then be evaluated on a regular grid. In the case of interpolation, the function is constrained to pass through all of your input datapoints exactly, whereas with smoothing this constraint is relaxed so that noise gets smoothed out. Scipy implements many different interpolation and smoothing methods, so I encourage you to look at the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

One option would be bicubic spline smoothing, e.g. [`scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline):

```
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

# play around with the s= parameter to control the degree of smoothing
spl = SmoothBivariateSpline(x, y, z)

# coordinates to evaluate the spline fit at
xeval = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
yeval = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)

# evaluate the spline fit
H = spl(xeval, yeval, grid=True)
```

You could then plot this as before, using `plt_surface`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'})
xe, ye = np.ix_(xeval, yeval)
ax.plot_surface(xe, ye, H, cmap='Blues', alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, 'ob')
```

[image]

---

Personally I'm not a big fan of 3D plots - whenever I see a 3D plot there is almost always a clearer way to represent the data in 2D. For example, you could plot irregularly sampled x,y,z data as a scatter plot, using marker size and/or color to represent the z-axis, e.g.:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, z, z, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]

You could also represent regularly sampled 2D data as a pseudocolor plot (`plt.pcolormesh`), image (`plt.imshow`), or contour plot (`plt.contour`/`plt.contourf`).

Take a look at the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) for some more examples.